# Setting the language and region settings in a Windows Docker Container

Tags: c#, .net, docker, frameworks

I'm creating a docker container based on the `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8` base image.

This image is set to `en_US`, meaning that all the Windows language and region settings and default location is set to United States.

What I need to do is to change this to `en_GB` and change the location to `United Kindom` for the default user because I have a .Net application which has a dependency on a 3rd party library that uses this to output data to Excel. However nothing I've tried seems to be able to change the language and region settings thus far.

Things I have tried so far:

1. Attempted to use the `intl.cpl` International Settings to import the settings and update the default user:

```
# Set Locale and language 
& $env:SystemRoot\System32\control.exe "intl.cpl,,/f:`"UKRegion.xml`""

# Set Languages/culture
Set-Culture en-GB
```

Contents of UKRegion.xml:

```
<gs:GlobalizationServices xmlns:gs="urn:longhornGlobalizationUnattend">
    <!--User List-->
    <gs:UserList>
        <gs:User UserID="Current" CopySettingsToDefaultUserAcct="true" CopySettingsToSystemAcct="true"/> 
    </gs:UserList>

    <!-- user locale -->
    <gs:UserLocale> 
        <gs:Locale Name="en-GB" SetAsCurrent="true"/> 
    </gs:UserLocale>

    <!-- system locale -->
    <gs:SystemLocale Name="en-GB"/>
    <!-- GeoID -->

    <gs:LocationPreferences>
        <gs:GeoID Value="242"/>
    </gs:LocationPreferences>

    <gs:MUILanguagePreferences>
        <gs:MUILanguage Value="en-GB"/>
        <gs:MUIFallback Value="en-US"/>
    </gs:MUILanguagePreferences>

    <!-- input preferences -->
    <gs:InputPreferences>
        <!--en-GB-->
        <gs:InputLanguageID Action="add" ID="0809:00000809" Default="true"/> 
    </gs:InputPreferences>
</gs:GlobalizationServices>
```

2. Setting the values before starting the application in a `powershell` script:

```
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale en-GB
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 242
Set-WinUserLanguageList -LanguageList (New-WinUserLanguageList -Language en-GB) -Force
Set-Location -Path "C:\\AppFolder"
.\AppExe.exe
```

After setting up the container and attaching I can see that `Get-WinHomeLocation` has updated, `Get-WinUserLanguageList` shows `en_GB` as an option, however the default language for windows from `Get-WinSystemLocale` still returns `en-US`

I also considered building my own base image from the en-GB Windows Server Core base image and running the framework setup that Microsoft runs to create the Framework runtime 4.8 image, but Microsoft don't seem to publish an en-GB base image!

Has anyone else come across this? How did you resolve it? Any other suggestions?

Comment: I've spent multiple days trying many methods, including but not limited to those above.  This appears to still be effectively impossible to do.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that a Docker container inherits language settings from the host when using Process Isolation. So, change the host's language settings as desired. In PowerShell, to set the Region you can do this:

```
Set-WinSystemLocale en-GB
Restart-Computer
```

Now run Docker:

```
docker run -it --isolation=process mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1909 PowerShell
```

Within the Docker shell:

```
Get-WinSystemLocale

LCID             Name             DisplayName
----             ----             -----------
2057             en-GB            English (United Kingdom)
```

Comment: If you run with Hyperv Isolation then the language is fixed as en-US with ANSI System Locale set to UTF-8 (65001). There is no known way to change this behaviour in hyperv

Comment: Adding to what @RobG says: They are aware of the issue but it is a significant change to support it https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/40535#issuecomment-930650879

Answer (score 2):

Probably you need only to trick the 'Get-Culture' result. If so, you can try this approach:

```
docker run --name temp-container --user "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" --isolation=process your-image:your-tag powershell Set-Culture en-AU

docker commit temp-container your-image:your-tag
docker rm temp-container
```

Now you can start your image:

```
docker run --rm -it --isolation=process your-image:your-tag powershell
```

And you will have culture 'en-AU'

Comment: That works, thanks! But that does not fix the `Invalid code page` error message that I have when I try to`chcp 850` from Gitlab's `.gitlab-ci.yaml`

Comment: Thanks. Also works in a `Dockerfile`. `FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/runtime:4.8
RUN Set-Locale de-DE` and `docker build -t my-image:my-tag`