# Windows Docker Image, change language, locale, Standard Encoding

Tags: docker, encoding, localization, vb6, locale

I'm trying to build our DotNet & VB6 Project in Docker. I got vb6 installed, this didnt work on windows server core so I had to use the pure Windows Image. So we can't use a localized server core Image to solve these. Because as far as I know there are no localized Images for Windows Images itself.

It all builds fine but with one error, for every ü,ä,ö,ß I have inside of a String in VB6, I just get  � at runtime.
I tried to change the encoding of the .cls files to UTF8, which worked at runtime, but now the VB6 IDE just displays Ã¼.

In Powershell:

```
Get-WinSystemLocale

Docker: 1033             en-US            English (United States)

My Workstation: 1031             de-DE            Deutsch (Deutschland)
```

So I tried Set-WinSystemLocale, but without any success.

```
[System.Text.Encoding]::Default

Docker: utf-8

My Workstation: Windows-1252
```

But this seems to be get only.

The default encoding the .cls files are using is ANSI, which to my unterstanding is just using the default encoding? If so where can this default be found and can it be changed?

Also I dont know if this provides any help, but I've read that VB6 is using Unicode internaly.

Any ideas or anything I've missed? This project can't die because of encoding issues.
And also migration to DotNet is not an Option at the moment.

EDIT:

Already tried this aswell.
[Setting the language and region settings in a Windows Docker Container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168226/setting-the-language-and-region-settings-in-a-windows-docker-container)

Comment: VB6 uses the "ANSI" encoding when reading the CLS files i.e. the default code page as set in Windows control panel. I'm suspicious of using UTF8 for the cls files. I'm not sure the IDE & compiler will like that. I recommend Windows 1252 assuming that supports the characters you need. It's true that VB6 at runtime stores its strings in Unicode internally, but for many purposes the strings are converted to/from "ANSI" i.e. the current code page in Windows. HTH

Comment: As far as I know you cannot hardcode characters like ü,ä,ö,ß  in a VB6 source file. Use `CHR$()` or its variants instead.

Comment: Hardcoding Umlauts in VB6 works just fine on a regular Windows machine (inc. Windows 10). So Docker does something fancy behind the scenes. @lukas-hankeln: if you look at the source code files with a text viewer in the Docker image, what's in there?