# Windows 10 Pro - Docker Container System Locale

Tags: windows, docker

My current laptop runs **Windows 10 Pro** with a system locale of da-DK, but I don't know why my **Window docker desktop** is running a **system locale of en-US**.

I am running in a Window environment. I saw a lot of people runs with other environment but I need Window part of helps.

Comment: Could you please run this command in powershell and check the output ? Get-WinSystemLocale

Comment: Found this SO post that might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58168226/setting-the-language-and-region-settings-in-a-windows-docker-container

Answer (score 2):

thank you @SomeStudent!

Summarising from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60519634/1872399:

---

- Process Isolation: It will use the Locale from the HOST (which is what I want)
- HyperV Isolation: It is hardcoded to en-US with Locale set to UTF-8